# how to bundle update the local gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm updating my local gem,

And update the version number after small every change.

Then I ran the `bundle update` to update to newest gem I made.

But when I ran `bundle update` it takes too much time to fetch the meta-data from remote server.

How could I force the `bundle update` only check my local server ?

```
Using beautiful_scaffold (0.3.4.2) from source at /Users/hsu-wei-cheng/sandbox/Beautiful-Scaffold
```

Comment: if you are using gem from your system and you have mentioned it in your Gemfile, then you don't need to bundle update every time when you make changes on your local gem.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should understand how it works

if you update you Gemfile with a new gem you don't need to run `bundle update` you should run `bundle install` and it will update your Gemfile.lock with the new gems and dependencies.

when you run bundle update there is a different that cause the time you mention:

1. if you didn't specified a version of gem it will take the latest gem version, mean it will search gem by gem for the latest version.
2. if you specified gem version `~>` it will take the latest patch of the gem.

this means always add version to your major gems it your Gemfile to avoid `bundle update` override version that your system based on.

cheers.